# gmetric data submitted doesn't follow dmax value

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool, ganglia

I have a custom script that is querying a metric port for an application that I'm running and submitting parsed values to ganglia via gmetric. The script runs every minute, so I submit the data to ganglia using the following gmetric options:

```
/usr/sbin/gmetric  -g ec2 -s positive -t uint32 -d 600 -n "$NAME" -v $VALUE -x 60
```

But for some reason there are still gaps in the graphing data:

[image]

Is there something in my formatting that is preventing the dmax/ttl of the last metric received from being honored? Is there anyone who does custom metric collection that has run into this problem before that can shed some insight or provide some tips as to how to best correct this?

Answer (score 0):

apparently ganglia doesn't work with counter metrics. closing this issue out. ganglia inserts data into rrds every 15 seconds, so for every value graphed there are 3 values that are the same, hence the 0 values.